# How to Loop through enum in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model in Django

```
class Order(models.Model):
   class Gender(models.IntegerChoices):
      Male = (1,), _("Male")
      Female = (2,), _("Female")
```

I want to send male and female in context

```
context["genders"] = Order.Gender
```

I use that in template like this

```
{% for gender in genders %}
   <p>{{ gender }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to show male and female in front

Comment: Try `{{ gender.get_gender_display }}`

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 1):

Pass choices to the template, unpack and display them:

views.py

```
context["genders"] = Order.Gender.choices
```

template.html

```
{% for key, gender in genders %}
    <p>{{ gender }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```